# Pass data from button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Html button

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Ban" , "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.UserName" name="username" />
                    <input type="button" id="username" value="Ban" class="btn-default" />
                }
```

And that is my controller action

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Ban(string username)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = db.Users.Find(username);
                user.isBaned = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Redirect("/Admin/");
            }
            return Redirect("/Admin/Index");
        }
```

And when I click the button it can't reach the action and nothings happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a **submit** button instead of a regular button:

```
<input type="submit" id="username" value="Ban" class="btn-default" />
```

so that the form gets submitted.